# Ladder slides down a wall

Tags: geometry, triangles

As shown in the figure, $AC$ is a ladder that slides downwards against the wall $AB$.

- Distance from $A=x$
- Distance from $C=y$

Options:

- $\text{(A)} \quad x > y$
- $\text{(B)} \quad y > x$
- $\text{(C)} \quad x = y$
- $\text{(D)} \quad \text{Relationship cannot be determined.}$

[image: Figure for this Question]

From my understanding, If a ladder slides down the wall, the length of the ladder remains the same, hence, $x$ (which gets reduced in number) should be equal to $y$ (which gets increased in number) in order to maintain the length of the ladder.

However the answer is D. 
i.e. Relationship cannot be determined.

Answer (score 3):

We have that

$$(AB-x)^2+(BC+y)^2=AB^2+BC^2$$

Which in the plane $x-y$ is a circle passing through the origin, for example for $AB=2$ and $BC=1$ we have

[image]

thus for some value $x=x_0$ we have

- $y=x$ for $x=x_0$
- $y>x$ for $x<x_0$
- $y<x$ for $x>x_0$

Comment: Gimusi.Very nice! Noting that $(x,y)$ satisfy the equation of a circle that can intersect $y=x$ at most twice. For all other points $x \not =y.$